# ¿Cómo puedo concatenar dos arreglos?

Tags: java

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de concatenar dos arreglos en java

```
String[] ar1={"h","o","l","a"};
String[] ar2={"m","u","n","d","o"};
```

para que posteriormente el arreglo resultante imprima todos los valores.

Answer (score 5):

Haciendo uso de la Interface  [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

```
String[] ar1={"h","o","l","a"};
String[] ar2={"m","u","n","d","o"};
String[] result = Stream.of(ar1, ar2).flatMap(Stream::of).toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Answer (score 2):

Como son del mismo tipo, es fácil concatenarlos usando un método de la clase [**System**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

1. Creas un nuevo array de longitud igual a la suma de las longitudes de los que quieres juntar:

   `String[] res = new String[ ar1.length + ar2.length ];`
2. Los guardas en el nuevo array:

   `System.arraycopy( ar1, 0, res, 0, ar1.length );`
   `System.arraycopy( ar2, 0, res, ar1.length, ar2.length );`

Los parámetros que recibe **arrayCopy()** son:
  Array de origen.
  Posición inicial del array origen.
  Array destino.
  Posición incial en el array de destino.
  Número de elementos a copiar.

Answer (score 1):

He encontrado esta respuesta en [`StackOverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-can-i-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java)

Código:

```
String[] ar1={"h","o","l","a"};
String[] ar2={"m","u","n","d","o"};
String[] concatenados= (String[])ArrayUtils.addAll(ar1, ar2);
```

Espero que te sirva, un saludo.

Mas información respecto a la clase [`ArrayUtils.addAll(T[], T...)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#addAll%28T%5B%5D,%20T...%29)

Comment: No conozco ninguna clase en el JDK llamada `ArrayUtils`. Por favor provee más detalle sobre dicha clase.

Answer (score 1):

Que yo sepa no hay ninguna función en Java que concatene dos arrays .

Podrías hacer algo como:

```
    String[] ar1={"h","o","l","a"};
    String[] ar2={"m","u","n","d","o"};
    String[] ar3 = new String[ar1.length + ar2.length];

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < ar1.length; i++ ){
        ar3[i] = ar1[i];

    }

    for (int a = 0; a < ar2.length; a++ ){

        ar3[i] = ar2[a];
        i++;
    }
```