# queria saber como meter 2 arreglos en 1 arreglo

Tags: java, netbeans, loops, array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui en mi programa solo toma 1 arreglo que es el a pero el b no lo toma :c

Comment: Te puede ayudar esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35656/c%C3%B3mo-puedo-concatenar-dos-arreglos, teniendo en cuenta que el tipo de dato cambia a _Int_ ;)

Comment: @Dev.Joel Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo puedo concatenar dos arreglos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35656/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-concatenar-dos-arreglos) jajaja sin contar con el mal formato que tiene :P

Answer (score 2):

Tu error está en que, dentro del `for`, estás guardando la posicion `i` de los `arrayA` y `arrayB` en la misma posicion `i` del `arrayC`. Una manera de hacerlo sería así:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int arrayA[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int arrayB[] = {6,7,8,9,10};

    int arrayC[] = new int[10];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        arrayC[i] = arrayA[i];
        arrayC[i+5] = arrayB[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arrayC.length; i++){
        System.out.println(arrayC[i]);
    }
}
```